# Nuxt.js dynamic static directory doesn't work in production

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt app its in universal mode, and has a feature that uploads or adds an image file to the static folder then I have a script that fetch all contents on that folder to display back to the front-end in an image tag, it works perfectly on Dev, but after Nuxt build, and running it on production (nuxt start), it doesn't work anymore.

When I checked the .nuxt folder, the upload script does not work anymore, but works perfectly on Dev.